# Joint Density of N Dependent Uniformly Distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability-distributions

Could someone show me the formula with proof for the Joint Density and CDF for N uniformly distributed variables that are not necessarily independent?
Again, if certain forms of dependence are assumed, please point that out in the answer.

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of two rvs' it is easy to show an example. Let $X$ be uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. Then define $Y$ so that it be uniformly distributed over $[0,X]$

The dependence is obvious: $X$ limits $Y$'s possibilities.

One can create an $n$ dimensional model based on the example above.

However, I don't think that there is a general cook book formula for creating dependent rvs'.

Comment: Please note, N could be 2, but is more likely to be more than 2.

Comment: Thanks Zoli, Could you please elaborate on how could one create an n dimensional model based on the above example and give complete details of the derivation or point to a source? What are the other forms of commonly used dependence structures?

Comment: Yes, @ravi.all.over. I modified my answer accordingly. ($X_1$ is a bound for $X_2$, $X_2$ is a bound for $X_3$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There are many joint density functions of N randoms for which each of the randoms is uniformly distributed (on, for concreteness, the interval $[0,1)$), yet they variables are not independent.  The formula will depend on whi8ch jdf you choose.

Here is an extreme example:  The $N$ variables are labeled $X_k | k = 0 \ldots N-1$ and variable $X_0$ is chosen as a uniform variate on $(0,1)$. Then for all $k > 0$, 
$$
X_k = \left( X_0 + \frac{k}{N} \right) \pmod 1
$$
(where $a \pmod 1$ means the fractional part of $a$; $1.6 \pmod 1 = 0.6$).

Here the jdf is 
$$
\text{jdf }(X_0 \ldots X_{N-1}) = \prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left[ \delta\left(X_k - \frac{k}{N} -X_0 \right) + \delta\left(X_k - \frac{k}{N} - X_0 -1 \right)\right]
$$

Comment: Thanks Mark. What is the delta here?

Comment: The delta function enforces that its argument be zero; thus for each $k$, $X_k - \frac{k}{N} = X_0$.  You find delta functions frequently when describing probability density functions relating to a discrete distribution.

Comment: Thanks Mark, Could you please address this other question? I am not sure if I should post this question here … But they are related … http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272351/n-affiliated-random-variables-conditional-density-and-distribution-of-first-ord